# How to get two data from FMDB and return a String combined two of them in swift?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, fmdb

I have two records in my database, 'FirstName and LastName and I wanna get two of them then return a FullName, showing FullNames in tableView. Using Swift3 and Xcode8.2.1, FMDB
here's the func of getFullName

```
    func getFullName() -> String{

    StudentDataBase.getInstance()
    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    let result : FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Student_info", withArgumentsIn: nil)
    let fullName  = (result?.string(forColumn: "FirstName"))! + " " + (result?.string(forColumn: "LastName"))!
    return fullName
}
```

sharedInstance is a global one, StudentDataBase is s singleton class:

```
class StudentDataBase : NSObject {

var database: FMDatabase? = nil
var pathToDB: String!

class func getInstance() -> StudentDataBase{

    if((sharedInstance.database) == nil)
    {
        sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Utility.getPath("data.db"))
    }
    return sharedInstance
}
```

and my Student.swift goes like this:

```
import UIKit

//the model class to fetch the data from data.db
class Student : NSObject {

    var studentID: String = String()
    var fstName: String = String()
    var lstName: String = String()
    var phoneNum: String = String()

}
```

I got a thread goes like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fBbP.png)
Thank you so much if anyone can help

After editing the Query into

```
    let result : FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT ifnull(FirstName,'') as FirstName, ifnull(LastName,'') as LastName FROM Student_info", withArgumentsIn: nil)
```

There's another error in combining them into one String:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5ayQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this crash because either you are getting `nil` for `FirstName` or `LastName`, and you can use `ifnull` with your select query and return empty string if it is nil. So change your query like this way.

```
let result : FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT ifnull(FirstName,'') as FirstName, ifnull(LastName,'') as LastName FROM Student_info", withArgumentsIn: nil)
```

**Note:** You haven't added `WHERE` clause with query so that this will give you all the records form `Student_info` table also it is batter if you check `result.next()` to confirm result contains records or not.

Comment: there's an error shows cannot invoke 'executeQuery' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Comment: @GraceYang Edit your question with code where you are getting error.

Comment: Finished, please have a look, and I'm totally new in swift and FMDB, so could you please be more specific or using common easy understanding language. I'll be very appreciate :)

Comment: @GraceYang You have changed whole function but I have told you to change only query check my edited answer.

Comment: It works thank you so much!!!! and how can I add them together? `let fullName  = (result?.string(forColumn: "FirstName"))! + " " + (result?.string(forColumn: "LastName"))!` this one also has error, I've edited the question and added the screenshot

Comment: @GraceYang Welcome mate :), Are you able to concatenate two string?

Comment: No I couldn't :( ,it shows `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, please see the second image, I'm quite dizzy by the code now XD

Comment: I was thinking maybe I didn't open the database at all?

Comment: @GraceYang Have you tried with open database, after that is it working.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @GraceYang I'm doesn't know that never work with FMDB. But you can prevent crash using optionally bind the value.     `let fullName  = (result?.string(forColumn: "FirstName")) ?? "" + " " + (result?.string(forColumn: "LastName")) ?? ""`

Write like this way.

Comment: I used [String] instead

Comment: @GraceYang Welcome mate that would be great that you have used `[String]`.